# NodeJS function not working

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

Hey am trying to add the parsed data to the table, but for some reason it's not getting added am still learning so I don't really know why I tried searching couldn't find anything

main.js:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let win;


app.on('ready', () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 1280, height: 1080});
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
    //win.setMenu(null);
    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })
});

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="design.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Today's Shows</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./jquery.min.js');</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page" class="yt-card">
    <section>
        <div class="tbl-header">
        </div>
        <div class="tbl-content">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%" id="myTable">
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script>
    var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
            $ = cheerio.load(`
        <tr name="hover" class="forum_header_border">
                <td class="forum_thread_post" width="35" align="center"><a href="/shows/1458/hunted/" title="Hunted Torrent"><img src="/images/eztv_show_info3.png" alt="Info" title="Hunted Torrents" border="0"></a></td>
                <td class="forum_thread_post">
                <a href="/ep/161087/hunted-2015-s02e06-720p-hdtv-x264-c4tv/" title="Hunted 2015 S02E06 720p HDTV x264-C4TV [eztv] (960.91 MB)"  class="epinfo">Hunted 2015 S02E06 720p HDTV x264-C4TV [eztv]</a>
        </td>
        <td class="forum_thread_post" align="center">
                <a href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:a489093124274c23d6f52d16c5dd73d5da018489&amp;dn=Hunted.2015.S02E06.720p.HDTV.x264-C4TV%5Beztv%5D.mkv%5Beztv%5D&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A80&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969" class="magnet" title="Hunted 2015 S02E06 720p HDTV x264-C4TV [eztv] (960.91 MB) Magnet Link" rel="nofollow"></a>
                <a href="https://zoink.ch/torrent/Hunted.2015.S02E06.720p.HDTV.x264-C4TV[eztv].mkv.torrent" rel="nofollow" class="download_1" title="Hunted 2015 S02E06 720p HDTV x264-C4TV Torrent: Download Mirror #1"></a>
                </td>
                <td class="forum_thread_post" align="center">960.91 MB</td>
        <td class="forum_thread_post" align="center">26m 58s</td>
        <td class="forum_thread_post" align="center"><span style="color: green; ">3</span></td>
                <td class="forum_thread_post_end" align="center"><a href="/forum/discuss/161087/" rel="nofollow" title="Discuss about Hunted 2015 S02E06 720p HDTV x264-C4TV [eztv]:"><img src="/ezimg/s/1/3/chat_empty.png" alt="Discuss" title="Discuss about this show" width="16" border="0" height="16"></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr name="hover" class="forum_header_border">
                <td class="forum_thread_post" width="35" align="center"><a href="/shows/1865/cant-pay-well-take-it-away/" title="Can't Pay? We'll Take It Away! Torrent"><img src="/images/eztv_show_info3.png" alt="Info" title="Can't Pay? We'll Take It Away! Torrents" border="0"></a></td>
                <td class="forum_thread_post">
                <a href="/ep/161084/cant-pay-well-take-it-away-s04e19-720p-hdtv-x264-c4tv/" title="Cant Pay Well Take It Away S04E19 720p HDTV x264-C4TV [eztv] (831.79 MB)"  class="epinfo">Cant Pay Well Take It Away S04E19 720p HDTV x264-C4TV [eztv]</a>
        </td>
        </tr>`);

    $('td.forum_thread_post').each(function () {

        var tElement = $(this).next();
        var dElement = tElement.next();
        var sElement = dElement.next();
        tElement = getTitle(tElement);

        var title = tElement.text();
        var website = tElement.attr('href');
        var download = getDownload(dElement);
        var size = sElement.text();

        if (!isEmpty(title) && !isEmpty(download) && !isEmpty(size) && !isEmpty(website)) {
            console.log(`Title: ${title}\n Download: ${download}\n Size:${size}\n Website: ${website}`);
            AddRow(website,size,title,download);
        }
    });

    function getDownload(dElement) {
        if (!isEmpty(dElement)) {

            for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
                var download = dElement.children(`a.download_${i}`).attr('href');
                if (!isEmpty(download)) {
                    return download;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    function getTitle(tElement) {
        if (!isEmpty(tElement)) {
            var title = tElement.children('a');
            if (!isEmpty(title)) {
                return title;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    function isEmpty(value) {
        return typeof value == 'string' && !value.trim() || typeof value == 'undefined' || value === null;
    }

    function AddRow(website,size,title,download) {
        var newRowContent = `<tr class="torItem"><td width="65.1%"><a class="download" target="_blank" href="${website}">${title}</a></td> <td width="8.5%">${size}</td> <td width="12%">FROM</td> <td width="12.9%"><a class="downbutton" href="${download}">Download</a></td></tr>`;
        $("#myTable").find("tbody").append(newRowContent);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: why the down vote am srs it's not getting added to the table..

Comment: Did you see any errors in console? i have point to say you have break lines not escaped.

Comment: No errors at all in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package cheerio is not for client side implementation. You could use jQuery for that.

Comment: Am using cheerio to parse the html once the parsing is done i add the data to the table, please look at the code.

Comment: Yes, I can see that however node can't execute the cheerio on your index.html

Comment: Am using electron and it's executing it's parsing the html as needed but when i try to add the row to the table it does not get updated.

Comment: Oh i see what you were mentioning to :D Thank you.